# C# SQLite Win 8.1 System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to program with SQLite on WinRT 8.1 on Visual Studio 2013. I installed SQLite with the WinRT 8.1 VSIX and the same one for Windows Phone 8.1 and also load the `sqlite-net` from nuget.

I use to get the following Error:

```
An exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in TimeTableAPP.Windows.exe but was not handled in user code
```

[image]

from this two lines of code:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection cneu = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("newDB.db");
await cneu.CreateTableAsync<TestTable>();
```

same with

```
var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "newDB.db"));
await cneu.CreateTableAsync<TestTable>();
```

with TestTable

```
[Table("TestTable")]
public class TestTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string nomnomnom { get; set; }
}
```

This issue seems to happen quite often and usually is solved by setting platform target to x86. As you can see I do so:

[image]

I have no idea what to try anymore. I ran a repair on the VC2013 installation, uninstalled and reinstalled the VSIX and made a project for shared Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, with Windows Phone NOT triggering the error, but Windows Store App triggering the error with the same code.

Comment: Can you use this instead? http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/

Comment: I'm not used to nuget, when I copy-paste the command, it gives me a successful return: 
Installing 'System.Data.SQLite 1.0.93.0'.
Successfully installed 'System.Data.SQLite 1.0.93.0'.
Adding 'System.Data.SQLite 1.0.93.0' to App2.
Successfully added 'System.Data.SQLite 1.0.93.0' to App2.
But I cannot add `using System.Data.SQLite`, nor `using SQLite` like before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this error occurs due to the formatting of a library or program being bad (usually mistmatched) - this can occur if your target is x86, but it can also occur if your target is explcitly x64 or there's a mismatch beyond your own code. Simply setting to x86 is not going to fix it if your program isn't x86. Make sure you try x64 and Any CPU, and check any available documentation on what SQLite says it's running under.

Also don't forget you can try to install the libraries directly instead of from NuGet, as there may be some conflict in the libraries themselves. outside of your control.

Comment: There cannot be a mismatch, as I created a new project with just the lines showing above. As you can see in my config file I did not set target to x64. changing it to `any cpu` does not the trick as you have to specify an architecture, compiling with target `x64` only triggers a `An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in App2.exe but was not handled in user code`

Comment: what do you mean with installing the libraries directly? I cannot use the dll's from sqlite.org, because it says `The project targets '.NETCore' while the file reference targets '.NETFramework'. This is not a supported scenario.`

Comment: Actually, x64 is fixing (part) of the problem. If you get a SQLite exception, that would mean it's entering code where before it was failing to load the DLL entirely. As for the use of '.NETCore' is likely a need to fix the project file itself

Comment: The new update from SQLite solved the problem, it seems, it was a known issue.